# Creating a cocos2d game that runs on ipad and iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I read a tutorial a while back and it seemed like the author got his application/game to run on ipad and iphone with the same code base. How is this done?

Is it really necessary to create 2 code bases for each version or how can it be run on both devices.

Obviously the size of the application will grow because of the resources, but is there a way to leave out things depending on the build target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to leave out the resources that are not used. 
It is just the resources that is different. 
Need to prepare 2 sets of images for iphone and ipad. 
Codes if you are using cocos2d .99.5, it should be fine.

In the targeted device family, select iphone/ipad.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad

He has really good cocos2d tutorials!